# muliplte counter timers not working on single page

Tags: php, countdown

i have multiple timers on a page but the code doesn't seem to work for it.

in the code below the timer for each post gets started with onload function which calls the jquery code

the code i used i got it from another thread here i just modified it to work with onload for each span but it doesn't work then

```
 <?php
$i=0;
$timeleft="05:00:30";
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<span id="countdown<?php echo $i; ?>" onload="start_timer(<?php echo $i; ?>,<?php echo $timeleft; ?>)"> <?php echo $timeleft; ?> </span>    
<?php $i++;endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function start_timer(num,time){
  $(document).ready(function() {  
      parts = time.split(':'),
      hours = +parts[0],
      minutes = +parts[1],
      seconds = +parts[2],
      span = $('#countdown'+num);

    function correctNum(num) {
      return (num<10)? ("0"+num):num;
    }

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        seconds--;
        if(seconds == -1) {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes--;

            if(minutes == -1) {
                minutes = 59;
                hours--;

                if(hours==-1) {
                  alert("timer finished");
                  clearInterval(timer);
                  return;
                }
            }
        }
        span.text(correctNum(hours) + ":" + correctNum(minutes) + ":" + correctNum(seconds));
    }, 1000);
  }); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: try passing the $timeleft as a string like `onload="start_timer(<?php echo $i; ?>,'<?php echo $timeleft; ?>')"`

Comment: did that not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[onload is only supported on the following elements](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

you can do something like this:

```
<?php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<span id="countdown<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $timeleft; ?> </span>
<script>start_timer(<?php echo $i; ?>,'<?php echo $timeleft; ?>');</script>
<?php $i++;endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

**Edit:**

change you javascript to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFormat(num){
    return (num < 10)? ("0"+num): num;
}
function StartTimer(num, time){
    this.parts = time.split(':');
    this.hours = this.parts[0];
    this.minutes = this.parts[1];
    this.seconds = this.parts[2];
    this.span = $('#countdown' + num);
}
StartTimer.prototype.myTimer = function(){
    var s = this.seconds;
    var m = this.minutes;
    var h = this.hours;
    var sp = this.span;
    var t = setInterval(function(){
        s--;
        if(s == -1) {
            s = 59;
            m--;
            if(m == -1) {
                m = 59;
                h--;
                if(h == -1) {
                    alert("timer finished");
                    clearInterval(t);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        //console.log();
        //console.log();
        //console.log();
        sp.text(h + ":" + myFormat(m) + ":" + myFormat(s));
    }, 1000);
};
</script>
```

and your while loop:

```
<?php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<span id="countdown<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $timeleft; ?> </span>
<script>new StartTimer(<?php echo $i; ?>,'<?php echo $timeleft; ?>').myTimer();</script>
<?php $i++;endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

you can also check it in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/roet8rvL/)

Comment: did that...the timer works only for the first post then...not working for rest